# Webstorm + Flow + React: Unresolved variable or type $Keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellij-idea, flowtype

I'm trying to follow the docs for declaring an enum in flow. The docs say to use one of these utility classes:
[Flow Utility classes: flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities)

When I follow the pattern listed in the docs:

```
// @flow
const countries = {
  US: "United States",
  IT: "Italy",
  FR: "France"
};

type Country = $Keys<typeof countries>;

const italy: Country = 'IT';
const nope: Country = 'nope'; // 'nope' is not a Country
```

Webstorm complains that $Keys is an unresolved variable or type.

Testing further, it also does this with $Values, $ReadOnly, and any of the other utility types.

My stack is CRA+Redux+Flow.

Stuff I've tried:

- I've searched around in circles with no answer. I found one source saying "install flow globally instead", I tried that, but it didn't work.
- Looking for ways to do an enum without a utility class: I'm sure there's a way, but I've not found it yet
- Flow *is* set as the Javascript type on webstorm
- Turning it off and back on

picture:
[image: Demonstrating the error]

Comment: Please make sure that you are familiar with this article: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/11/using-flow-in-webstorm/

Comment: I already am. "Flow is set as the Javascript type on webstorm"

Comment: Is there any errors or warnings `webstorm` highlights to you (I mean not about the code you're editing, but the app itself)?

Comment: nope, I checked webstorm's event log and all is ok. The variables are just not being seen in the global scope at all.

Comment: could you please attach a screenshot of what you've got?

Comment: The code block I included in the question, when pasted in, has the error.

Comment: I have the same issue in webstorm. Found https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000744584-Flow-unresolved-type-ReadOnlyArray but it seems not to be so hepful

Comment: Yea, I've found a couple places debating it, but no real solution. I was kind of hoping to set typing up so the jr devs could use autocompletion on things like my action status codes for async IPC calls...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The freshly new **Webstorm 2018.3** actually solves that problem finally. Please [upgrade](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/whatsnew/).

It was reported in this [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32425) which is marked as solved now. I tested the new version and it indeed works!